# Нарушение прав доступа при чтении

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте. Имеется такой код:

```
int**** submatrix; //Матрица подматриц
submatrix = Submatrix(matrix, rows, cols);
for (int i=0; i<rows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++){
        TurnAroundTheColumn(&submatrix[i][j], rows, cols); //В каждой подматрице повернуть столбцы относительно среднего столбца этой подматрицы
    }
}
TurnAroundTheRow(&submatrix, rows,cols); //Повернуть подматрицы относительно средней строки матрицы

bool TurnAroundTheColumn(int*** submatrix, int rows, int cols) {
    if(cols % 2 == 0)return false;
    for(int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
        for(int i = 0, j = cols - 1; i != j; i++, j++) {
            int temp = (*submatrix)[r][i];
            (*submatrix)[r][i] = (*submatrix)[r][j]; //Вот тут ошибка
            (*submatrix)[r][j] = temp;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

bool TurnAroundTheRow(int***** matrix, int rows, int cols) {
    if(rows % 2 == 0)return false;
    for(int c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
        for(int i = 0, j = rows - 1; i != j; i++, j++) {
            int** temp = (*matrix)[i][c];
            (*matrix)[i][c] = (*matrix)[j][c]; //И тут тоже
            (*matrix)[j][c] = temp;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Помогите пожалуйста понять, в чём моя ошибка?

```
//На всякий случай
int**** Submatrix(int** matrix, int rows, int cols) {
    int**** submatrix = new int***[rows];
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        submatrix[i] = new int** [cols];
    }
    for(int r = 0; r < rows * rows; r += rows) {
        for(int c = 0; c < cols * cols; c += cols) {
            int** temp = InitializeSubmatrix(rows, cols);
            for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
                for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                    temp[i][j] = matrix[r + i][c + j];
                }
            }
            submatrix[r / rows][c / cols] = temp;
        }
    }
    return submatrix;
}
```

Comment: Вау, `int****`. Это же чистый C, тут C++-ом и не пахнет.

Переходите на C++, получите type safety, стандартные контейнеры и забудете о рассуждениях типа "а это указатель на первый элемент или указатель на указатель на первый элемент?".

Comment: %username% не знаком со структурами?

Comment: Если C++, напишите class Matrix и class Submatrix. Если это хотя бы C, используйте typedef. Потому что я лично сбился со счёта, пытаясь догадаться, указателем на что является `int*****`, о каком восстановлении логики может идти речь? Вы пишете на ассемблере с сишным синтаксисом.

Comment: Это вы называете "легче"? Опишите, пожалуйста, словами семантику первого аргумента функции `TurnAroundTheRow`, вам сразу станет ясно.

---
C или C++ — определяется не формальным использованием оператора new, а использованием стандартных для языка идиом. Идиоматически, вы пишете на ассемблере.

Comment: Нет, `int**` — это указатель на указатель на `int`, _ничто_ в вашем коде не говорит, что это матрица.

Надо так:

    template<typename T>
    class matrix
    {
      public:
        Т operator () (int row, int column) { ... }
    };

`matrix<int>` — матрица типа `int`.

`matrix< matrix<int> >` — матрица, каждый элемент которой есть матрица типа `int`.

`matrix< matrix<int> >*` — указатель на матрицу, каждый элемент которой есть матрица типа `int`.

Comment: Сделайте свой код понятным, находить ошибки станет на порядок легче.

Comment: @VladD, я понимаю, что это указатель на указатель на int, но так как я работаю с матрицами, мне проще представлять, что это матрицы.
Так как я пока не знаком ни с классами, ни с шаблонами, приходиться довольствоваться тем, что есть

Comment: Уже нельзя. Код, в котором пять звёздочек подряд — ужасен и непригоден к поддержке и модификации. Уровень сложности вашей задачи требует, чтобы вы выучили классы и шаблоны, и затем вернулись к ней снова. То, что вы делаете, аналогично попытке написать искусственный интеллект на микрокалькуляторе.

---
Может быть, кто-нибудь захочет продраться через дебри вашего кода, и найдёт ошибку, но это вам не поможет, потому что вы сможете заставить _такой_ дизайн работать только через силу. Ошибки неизбежны.

Comment: Действительно пора взяться за изучение классов, так как без них довольно трудно. Но эту задачу мне всё равно придется допилить, так как сдавать её уже завтра надо :). Попробую тогда заново переписать эти функции, вдруг ошибка всплывёт.

Comment: > мне проще представлять, что это матрицы

Вот здесь и проблема. Вы держите в уме, что указатель на головной элемент списка указателей на головные элементы списков, представляющих строки (или столбцы?) матрицы — это как бы и есть матрица. А указатель на указатель на на головной элемент списка указателей на головные элементы списков матриц, это тоже матрица, но другая. И для того, чтобы работать с вашим кодом, нельзя об этом забывать ни на секунду.

Абстрагируйтесь! Сделайте матрицу абстрактных сущностей, реализуйте её один раз и забудьте навсегда о том, как именно внутри она устроена.

Comment: Автор, если уж не хотите использовать классы, то сделайте хотя бы внятные typedef-ы.

Comment: Submatrix выглядит подозрительно. `submatrix[r / rows][c / cols] = temp;` — вы записываете много раз в один и тот же элемент.

Comment: А ещё

    for(int i = 0, j = cols - 1; i != j; i++, j++)

— бесконечный цикл же. Сначала переменные неравны, потом вы их каждый раз увеличиваете на 1, так что снова будут не равны и т. д.

Comment: @VladD, проблема решилась, спасибо :)

Comment: @devnicor, а основную матрицу (отвлекитесь от субматриц) Вы как делаете?

Вообще-то говоря, **правильная** матрица целых - это `int *` (причем независимо от количества размерностей, 1, 2, 3 иди 10). Просто нужно понять, как обращаться к `matrix[i][j]` (для двумерной) или `matr3[i][j][k]` - трехмерной  и т.д.

Советую сначала как следует разобраться с вычислением адреса элемента в обычном одномерном массиве, а дальше продолжить методом математической индукции.

--

И тогда всякие `int*****` сами собой пропадут. Читайте, экспериментируйте, печатайте адреса (см. `man printf`).

Comment: @devnikor: отлично, а в чём была проблема? (Вы всё же выучите классы, код станет намного понятнее.)

Comment: @avp: вы имеете в виду хранение матрицы целым куском? Потому что ТС выделяет динамически строки по отдельности, и хранит список указателей на них. Такой подход тоже ведь имеет право на жизнь, как вы считаете?

Comment: @VladD, да, целым куском, и да, конечно имеет. 

Если кому-то важней привычно писать `a[i][j]`, чем `a[i*columns + j]`, то пусть изощряется (в т.ч. с разными функциями для работы со статическими (или в стеке) и "динамическими" матрицами).

Comment: @avp: на мой вкус, разницу между обоими вариантами надо бы спрятать в класс. Особенно хорошо достоинства такого подхода иллюстрирует код в данном вопросе.

Comment: @VladD, конечно, это решается классом, темплейтами и переопроеделением операций.

В общем, подходом - "Зачем просто, если можно сложно?". 

Зато академично и по своему красиво. Многим нравится.

Comment: @VladD, проблема была в этом:

    for(int i = 0, j = cols - 1; i != j; i++, j++)//Надо j--
    for(int i = 0, j = rows - 1; i != j; i++, j++)//И тут

А всё остальное работает, спасибо всем за помощь.

Comment: @avp: Мне, например, нравится. Например, тем, что код, работающий с матрицей `int`-ов такой же, как и код, работающий с матрицей матриц. В результате повторы кода сокращаются до минимума, вероятность ошибки падает, багфиксы делаются равно в одном месте. Мне "пятизвёздочный код" кажется существенно более сложным.

Comment: @VladD, и мне пяти(и даже трех)-звездочный код кажется очень сложным. Я его даже толком смотреть не стал. 

А вот утверждение

     что код, работающий с матрицей int-ов такой же, как и код, работающий с матрицей матриц. В результате повторы кода сокращаются до минимума, вероятность ошибки падает

весьма спорно. Это из области "благими намереяниями дорога в ад выложена". 

На самом деле растет вероятность появления редких и сложных ошибок в реализации и вообще-то неочевидность даже на верхнем уровне (там где `a[i][j]`).

Кто-то из авторов awk писал о такой вот неочевидности C++ программ.

Comment: @avp: Ну, с классами и шаблонами появляется типобезопасность. Смотрите: если мы и указатель на число, и массив, и матрицу из чисел, и матрицу из матриц передаём как бесструктурный `int*`, при попытке использовать его "не так" не происходит _ничего_, не предупреждения компилятора, ни креша (если не повезёт). С классами всё же компилятор не даст использовать матричный элемент массива как число. По поводу квадратных скобок -- это известная проблема синтаксиса C++, [обсуждалась](http://hashcode.ru/questions/178553/) не так давно.

Comment: @avp: ещё одно различие, о котором нужно думать (кстати, совершенно не являющееся проблемой в C#) — это копирование элементов. Если копирование целых чисел практически бесплатно, то излишняя копия матрицы дорога, и требует правильно определённых перегруженных операций (которые не имеют ничего общего с семантикой матрицы, а нужны только языку). Решение — хранить в структуре (матрице, контейнере, и т. п.) _указатели_ на матрицы (собственно, как это и делает C#), дорогие и ненужные копии отпадают.